# zIndex not working properly in react-native in IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, z-index

I only have 1 image that needs a `zIndex` to show it in front. It works on Android but it doesn't show up in IOS devices. Not sure why.

Here is the picture for Android:
[image]

Here is the picture for IOS:
[image]

As you can see, the user image doesn't appear in IOS.

Code is like this:

```
 <View>
      <Image
        source={require("./images/user-img.png")}
        style={{width:95,height:95,marginTop:10,marginLeft:135,position:'absolute',zIndex:1}}
      />
      <ImageBackground
        source={require("./images/bg-img.png")}
        style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%"}}>
        <View>
         //extra code here
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
 </View>
```

Anyone know the reason?

Comment: try zindex with   elevation  {elevation: 1000,zIndex:1000}

Answer (score 33):

Please add zindex to parent view.
In iOS, the zIndex doesn't work for nested parentView.
You need to make the parentView has high zIndex, and then target View again.

```
<View style={{zIndex: 10}}>
  <Image
    source={require("./images/user-img.png")}
    style={{width:95,height:95,marginTop:10,marginLeft:135,position:'absolute',zIndex:20}}
  />
  <ImageBackground
    source={require("./images/bg-img.png")}
    style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%"}}>
    <View>
     //extra code here
    </View>
  </ImageBackground>
```

Comment: Oh wow, this makes no sense at all but solved my issue. React Native is so weird! Thanks!

Comment: Thank u :) I Spent one entire day trying to figure it out what was wrong.

Comment: if your elements are meant to be **clickable**, you would need to tweak it a bit cause adding `zIndex` to parent fixes iOS but messes up android. `<View style={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? {zIndex: 10} : {}}>  <Button style={{zIndex: 99, elevation: 99}}> Clickable </Button></View> `

Answer (score 0):

Try rendering the background image first and then the profile image

```
<View>
  <ImageBackground
    source={require("./images/bg-img.png")}
    style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%"}}>
    <View>
     //extra code here
    </View>
  </ImageBackground>
  <Image
    source={require("./images/user-img.png")}
    style={{width:95,height:95,marginTop:10,marginLeft:135,position:'absolute',zIndex:1}}
  />
</View>
```